# How to detect if browser address bar is showing on iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, html, ipad

Is there a way to consistently detect if the browser address bar is showing?

We have a HTML5 app and want to show a special link if the address bar is showing, encouraging users to add the app to their home screen for a better experience.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the window.innerHeight property. 
That is the height of the content on screen. 
The value of that decrease a lot when the address bar is visible.

You may need to test out the decrease in height on different device to make that work better

Comment: The address bar seems to be independent of the viewport, I haven't had any luck with this suggestion

Comment: This seems to work in portrait mode but not in landscape.